# How can I create a CNContact with a CNPostalAddress?

Tags: swift, cncontact, cnpostaladdress

I tried this:

```
    let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.namePrefix = data["firstName"] as! String
    contact.nameSuffix = data["lastName"] as! String
    contact.organizationName = data["company"] as! String
    contact.jobTitle = data["jobTitle"] as! String

    let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
    address.street = data["street"] as! String
    address.city = data["city"] as! String
    address.state = data["state"] as! String
    address.postalCode = data["zipcode"] as! String
    address.country = data["country"] as! String

    contact.postalAddresses = [address]
```

And I received this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CNMutablePostalAddress' to expected element type 'CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>'
```

So, I tried this:

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.namePrefix = data["firstName"] as! String
    contact.nameSuffix = data["lastName"] as! String
    //contact.birthday =
    contact.organizationName = data["company"] as! String
    contact.jobTitle = data["jobTitle"] as! String

    let street = CNLabeledValue(label: "street", value:data["street"] as! NSString)
    let city = CNLabeledValue(label: "city", value:data["city"] as! NSString)
    let state = CNLabeledValue(label: "state", value:data["state"] as! NSString)
    let postalCode = CNLabeledValue(label: "zipcode", value:data["zipcode"] as! NSString)
    let country = CNLabeledValue(label: "country", value:data["country"] as! NSString)

    contact.postalAddresses = [street, city, state, postalCode, country]
```

And I received this error:

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'CNLabeledValue<NSString>' to expected element type 'CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>'
```

And I don't know how to create `CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>`.

Do you know the right way to create a `CNContact` with a `CNPostalAddress`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mistaking the usage of `CNLabeledValue`. Try this:

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.namePrefix = data["firstName"] as! String
contact.nameSuffix = data["lastName"] as! String
contact.organizationName = data["company"] as! String
contact.jobTitle = data["jobTitle"] as! String

let address = CNMutablePostalAddress()
address.street = data["street"] as! String
address.city = data["city"] as! String
address.state = data["state"] as! String
address.postalCode = data["zipcode"] as! String
address.country = data["country"] as! String

let labeledAddress = CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>(label: CNLabelHome, value: address) //<- You can create other `CNLabeledValue<CNPostalAddress>`s with other `CNLabelXxxx`s or your custom label.

contact.postalAddresses = [labeledAddress]
```

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks !